# Why is otool truncating my disassembly output?

Tags: macos, lldb, disassembly, mach-o, otool

When I run this command

```
otool -t binary
```

`otool` will correctly dump the text section of `binary`. E.g.

```
0000000100002100   55 48 89 e5 41 56 53 48 8b 35 32 24 54 00 4c 8b 
:
```

But when I run this command:

```
otool -tvV binary
```

`otool` skips a huge part of the text section:

```
00000001003a32ce pushq %rbp
:
```

The first 3805646 bytes are simply skipped and not disassembled. If I open the binary in `lldb`, I can disassemble code at the skipped addresses just fine.

Has anyone ever made similar experiences? Does `otool` maybe have an internal size limit and truncates sections beyond that limit? Has anyone discovered a work-around or knows a comparable tool that is available for free?

I tried to disassemble the whole binary with `lldb`:

```
lldb binary
(lldb) dis -s 0x100002100 -e ...
```

Setting `-e` to the address of the last byte in the text section but that doesn't work either. Actually `lldb` stops output after disassembling about 5000 bytes of the text section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before and I believe `otool` is (annoyingly) skipping to the first symbol. If you do `nm -n binary`, is the first defined symbol at `00000001003a32ce`?

Xcode ships with another tool, called `otool-classic`, that seems to disassemble the whole text segment. Presumably, it's an older version of `otool` before a rewrite or something like that. While it gets the whole text segment, it's possible it is less featureful in other ways (such as decoding references to selectors or strings). To invoke it, you use `xcrun otool-classic <args>`.

In my testing, you can also use the version of `otool` that comes with an earlier version of Xcode. The ones from Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 6.4 don't have this problem. (Those are the ones I happen to have handy to test. Others probably also work.)

Comment: You could be right here. The 1st symbol with an address is at `0x100000000`, but that's just `mh_execute_header`, which is not really symbol but serves as a base offset. The 2nd one is at `0x1003a32ce` and this one is the first "real" symbol. The disassembly seems to start there, skipping anything before it. Wow, that's crazy. I'll try an older otool and see what happens.

Comment: Yup, you are totally correct. I tried `otool` from Xcode 7.3.1 and it works as expected, so this seems clearly a bug. Have you reported it to Apple already? Guess I will do that now, even if it gets closed as dupe. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Okay, it seems `otool` of 7.3.1 is not working correctly either. It is dissembling everything before the first symbol, yet nothing after it. Only combing the output of both results in assembly code of the whole binary.

Comment: Hmm. In the test case I have, the one from 7.3.1 disassembles the whole text segment, not just up to the first symbol. I also just noticed that there's an `otool-classic` command in both Xcode 7.x and Xcode 8.x. It also seems to work. You can invoke it using `xcrun otool-classic <args>`.

Comment: `otool-classic` indeed works correctly, it really disassembles all of it! I don't know why the 7.3.1 didn't work correctly for me... maybe because I didn't changed the command line entirely to 7.3.1 (was still set to 8.2.1) and just called otool directly from within the 7.3.1 bundle? But with otool-classic, we have a perfect solution. You may like to add this to the answer as I think that this is the perfect answer for most people with a similar problem.

Comment: There also `jtool` being highly compatible with otool and having some arm disassembling capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reply and comments of Ken Thomases I made some tests with `otool` from older Xcode version and found out that `otool` in Xcode 7.3.1 works better but also won't disassemble the whole text section. I filed a bug report to Apple and here's the outcome:

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based
>   on the following information:
>
> The implementation of otool(1) changed in Xcode 8 to be based on
>   llvm-objdump(1) from the old otool-classic(1), which is still on the
>   system.
>
> For the llvm community, the current behavior of starting disassembly
>   from the first known symbol is the behavior the llvm community
>   desires.

And indeed, `otool-classic` works as desired (`xcrun otool-classic` will work), just like Ken already pointed out in his comments but I'm not happy with that reply and so I will now file a bug at the LLVM project.